# Twitter direct follow link (not button)

Tags: twitter

I'd like to allow people visiting my blog to follow me on Twitter. The actual problem is the Twitter officiel follow button does not really fit on my website (http://thomaskowalski.net, at the bottom of the page), I'd like it to be in the same style as the other links. I saw in the code that the button is actually a link (starting with the link tag a). So I tried to remove the class attribute, but now it's just a link to my twitter profile, which is the same at the right (Twitter link). So have you an idea of how to do to create a automatic follow button, with no user confirmation but without the ugly Twitter style.
Thank you :)

Comment: I'm not really sure (I would need to inspect twitter's source code), but I suspect they may be using the class name in that <a> tag (the "twitter-follow-button") for finding that specific link by their javascript, so if you remove or change the class name it's very likely twitter's JS won't run properly and therefore it won't give you any nice styling/buttons.

Comment: Yeah I had thought of this... but that means I can't add my own style to the button, right ?

Comment: Possibly you could still add your own class name, like: class="twitter-follow-button myownclassname"

Comment: So there would be two classes on the same element ?

Comment: yes, but that's perfectly legit.

Comment: It looks like Twitter's javascript for this widget actually creates an iframe around the button, making it difficult to style.